# Simulating PDA browser behavior and output

Tags: mobile, device-emulation, mobile-browser

I'm working on a website that will eventually have a version that is optimized for mobile devices.

Is there a decent way / method / place where I can simulate or emulate a wide variety of the available browsers and screens for the various mobile devices?

I would really like to try and capture as large of a group as possible, including the iPhone, various Blackberry devices, and some of the Windows Mobile devices.

Any suggestions for sites / software that I could give a go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing) question.